# React hook form - all fields are mandatory if any of the field is filled else optional

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hook-form

React hook form - form is completely optional or completely mandatory (if any of the field is filled). Please help the optimized way. Thanks.

Comment: can you elaborate more?

Comment: @BhruguTundeliya I have a form that the fields are optional. But all the fields will be mandatory only if any of the fields is filled.

Comment: show me your current code snippet i will edit that.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, you want to submit the form with default/empty
values only if none of the fields have been modified, and otherwise all
fields need to have filled values?

The simplest approach I believe would be to use the `isDirty` prop of `formState` to set the
`required` prop in the register function.

```
const {
    register,
    handleSubmit,
    formState: { errors, isDirty },
} = useForm();

return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(() => {})}>
        <TextField
            label={'optional1'}
            error={!!errors.optional1}
            {...register('optional1', { required: isDirty })}
        />
        <TextField
            label={'optional2'}
            error={!!errors.optional2}
            {...register('optional2', { required: isDirty })}
        />
        <Button color="inherit" type="submit">
            Create
        </Button>
    </form>
);
```

This way however, e.g. text fields
remain dirty after emptying some added input. So you would need to add a  some form reset functionality such as a reset-button to fix that.

Although, instead of a reset button, I would check that the field values equal default/empty values.
Note that the checking will require a bit more code if you have different kinds of fields or different default values. A reset button might be nice in this case also if you have a lot of fields though.

```
const {
    register,
    handleSubmit,
    watch,
    formState: { errors },
} = useForm();
const fieldValues = Object.values(watch());
const someOptionalFilled = fieldValues.some(fieldValue => fieldValue != '')

return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(() => {})}>
        <TextField
            label={'optional1'}
            error={!!errors.optional1}
            {...register('optional1', { required: someOptionalFilled })}
        />
        <TextField
            label={'optional2'}
            error={!!errors.optional2}
            {...register('optional2', { required: someOptionalFilled })}
        />
        <Button color="inherit" type="submit">
            Create
        </Button>
    </form>
);
```

Comment: does fieldValues update when any field is changed ? as far as i know `getValues()` is not subscribed to latest value changes

Comment: Good point. The update to `getValues` happens at submit, which is too late. I changed `getValues` to [`watch`](https://react-hook-form.com/docs/useform/watch). Should work better now.